# Link TFS test run to a release via c#

Tags: c#, tfs

Using the new TFS api:
Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer. ExtendedClient
I have succeeded creating a test run and attaching a release and release environment to it so a link to the release appears at the test run summery. 
However, when I go to the release page and click the "Tests" tab I cannot see the test run and it's statistics.
How can I "make" the release know the test run and add it to the release via c# code?

Here is my code:

```
  // Creates a TFS test run 
  public static void CreateTestRun(ITestPlan testPlan, int testCaseId, string testResult, 
        string buildIdStr, string releaseUri, string releaseEnvironmentUri, string testRunName)
    {
        // --------------------------------Biuld the RunCreateModel for the test run:------------------------------------------------
        // Find the test points of the current test case
        List<int> testPointIds = new List<int>();
        ITestPointCollection testPoints = testPlan.QueryTestPoints("SELECT * FROM TestPoint WHERE testPoint.TestCaseId='" + testCaseId + "'");
        foreach (ITestPoint testPoint in testPoints)
        {
            testPointIds.Add(testPoint.Id);
        }
        int buildId;
        int.TryParse(buildIdStr, out buildId);
        // Init RunCreateModel:
        RunCreateModel runCreateModel = new RunCreateModel(
        name: testRunName,
        startedDate: DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/y h:m:s tt"),
        plan: new ShallowReference(id: testPlan.Id.ToString()),
        pointIds: testPointIds.ToArray(),
        buildId: buildId,
        releaseUri: releaseUri,
        releaseEnvironmentUri: releaseEnvironmentUri
        );
        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // -------------------------------------------------Create test run in progress--------------------------------------------
        TestManagementHttpClient testManagementClient =
            new TestManagementHttpClient(new Uri(TFS_COLLECTION_NAME), new VssCredentials());
        // Use RunCreateModel to create a test run on TFS (using the extended API):
        TestRun testRunExtended =
            testManagementClient.CreateTestRunAsync(runCreateModel, TFS_TEAM_PROJECT_NAME).Result;
        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Using the regular client api, add results to the test run to complete it:
        TfsTeamProjectCollection tfsCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(TFS_COLLECTION_NAME), new VssCredentials());
        ITestManagementService testManagement = tfsCollection.GetService<ITestManagementService>();
        IEnumerable<ITestRun> testRuns = testManagement.QueryTestRuns(
            "SELECT * FROM TestRun WHERE TestRunID='" + testRunExtended.Id + "'");
        ITestRun testRun = testRuns.First();
        // Update the outcome of the test       
        ITestCaseResultCollection results = testRun.QueryResults();
        foreach (ITestCaseResult result in results)
        {
            result.Outcome = testResult == "Pass" ?
                Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestOutcome.Passed :
                Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestOutcome.Failed;
            result.State = TestResultState.Completed;
            result.Save();
        }
        testRun.Save();
        testRun.Refresh();
    }
```

Thx.

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: Hi, I just added

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by setting the RunCreateModel.isAutomated property to true.

Answer (score 0):

You could use REST API to [update test run by its ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/test/runs/update?view=vsts-rest-5.0), the api is as below:

```
PATCH https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/test/runs/{runId}?api-version=5.0-preview.2
```

You need to modify or add the following part in the body:

```
"releaseUri": "vstfs:///ReleaseManagement/Release/{releaseID}",
"releaseEnvironmentUri": "vstfs:///ReleaseManagement/Environment/{releaseID}",
"release": {
    "id": {releaseID},
    "name": "{releaseName}",
    "environmentId": {releaseID},
    "environmentName": "{EnvironmentName}",
    "definitionId": {definitionId},
    "environmentDefinitionId": {definitionId},
    "environmentDefinitionName": null,
    "attempt": 1
},
```

I've tested on my side, it's working.